# How to Display a List of Result Sources and

Tags: search, result-source

I know how to create a result source and I can add this as a search vertical to a search center. But my client wants something else.

Specifically, Customer Service wants to be able to go to their team site and see a list of links that are predefined searches. Then clicking on any such link would give them a list of documents defined by those searches.

As I said, I can define the search but I am not sure how to display a list of links to those searches (besides using search verticals). But I could have 15 or 20 of these predefined searches and that does not seem like a good use of search verticals.

What is the best practice to help my client achieve what they envision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a standard links list from SharePoint. Add link items to the list in the same URL format that you see on the search Results page. Like `https://sharepoint/search/pages/results.apsx?k=keyword`

Comment: Well duh. That was just too easy. After figuring out how to add those dang  verticals and display templates, it never occurred to me to just do something easy. Thanks for the smack on the head. Doh!